# Add fields to user roles

Tags: 7, entities, users

I'm using Drupal 7 to create a project linking organizations to volunteers. My initial approach is to use profile module to create different profiles for each role (volunteer & organization). Is it possible to create new fields which would attach only to a selected role?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a great example use-case for the [Profile 2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) module.

As listed on the project page:

> Profile2 allows for creating multiple profile types, which may be assigned to roles via permissions (e.g. a general profile + a customer profile)

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't quite the use case I'm after. I don't want to add additional profiles to users by role, I want to extend roles to have more fields. For instance: a profile type: Volunteer, and a profile type: Organization, each with their distinct fields. Profile2 seems to handle this rather awkwardly...

Comment: @starsinmypockets In Drupal 7, fields are added to nodes, comments, taxonomy terms, and users. There isn't a way to add a field to roles, which are not considered entities. The closer you can get is what reported by @tim.plunkett, which is to have a different profile type for each user having specific roles.

Comment: From an OO perspective, I'm basically trying to extend the user entity, although coding entirely new entities to use as roles seems like a lot of work ;)

Answer (score 3):

I guess you could also try to add all fields to the user directly and then use a custom [hook_field_access()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.api.php/function/hook_field_access/7) implementation to control when they are shown for edit/view.

Comment: This sounds promising!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use https://drupal.org/project/user_role_field
This module allows you to specify role specific fields. When creating a new field, you specify for what roles this field is enabled..

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a good idea to collect all fields in one entity. You could then have a enumerator-field, where you could choose entity-sub-type (organization or volunteer). That would be needed in case the author had authority to create both.
You can use [User Role Field](http://drupal.org/project/user_role_field) to hide the fields that the author is not allowed to see.
You can use [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) to restrict access that the author and viewer is not allowed to access.
You can use also hide or show fields dependent on values of other fields with [Conditional Fields](http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields). The dependee field would then be the enumerator-field. 
You could probably use [Computed Field](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field) to add extra logic dependent on sub-type.

I like to use taxonomy for enumerator, but it could be a text list instead.

You would probably also like to group the subtype specific fields together in a drupal.org/project/field_group

This pattern could just as well be applied on contenttypes. I think I will try it out.

In Microsoft Sharepoint, ContentTypes has had inheritance for years. I wonder if it will come in a future Drupal version.